# what are the different types of inheritance?

Tags: inheritance

Do salesforce supports all types of inheritance?
what are the limitations in in-heritance?
where can i get the exact material related to inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Apex inheritance is discussed in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_extending.htm).

Basically, a class can implement any number of interfaces but can only extend a single class (double or multiple inheritance is not supported).

There are then specific restrictions around virtual classes and virtual and abstract methods you can also find in the documentation.

Note that Salesforce SObjects do not support inheritance; you cannot extend one object type with another. You can, however, link SObjects together using Lookup fields, and MasterDetail fields, which sort-of gives you "composition" and "encapsulation".